# LC.EXE on 32bit windows running against an x64 assembly

Tags: .net, build-process, 32bit-64bit

I am building a x64 C#.NET application on a x86 version of windows and everthing works fine until the LC.EXE runs.

LC : error LC0000: 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///xxxx.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'

Now xxxx.dll contains components which are licensed and hence the executable which references xxxx.dll has entries in it's Properties\licenses.licx file for some components. From digging around it seems that since LC.exe is a 32bit application it cannot instantiate the licensed components in xxxx.dll as they are built for x64. Since I can't run a 64bit version of LC.exe I think I may be stuck. Does anyone know if a) my assumptions are correct and b) is there any way around my problem short of purchasing a 64bit machine. And in case anyone mentions it, I'd rather not compile xxxx.dll as AnyCPU.
Many thanks..

Comment: Have you been able to work around this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 64bit version of LC.exe?

ie  look in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64`

[Edit] Oh I didn't read correctly you were on 32bit machine. You are building a 64bit app on a 32bit machine?   If yes, then I agree you're stuck. You now have a good reason to upgrade to a new motherboard/cpu. btw, your current hardware may support x64 so you might be able to get away with just an OS reinstall.